# Sharepoint 2013 calendar days in rows instead of columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to align the days of a 2013 S/p calendar vertically instead of horizontally.  If there isn't a way to do that, is it possible to view the calendar as a list where I could modify the list settings to show Sunday on top of Monday on top of Tuesday, etc?  I don't have the ability to modify code, but do have S/p Designer 2013 as an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a regular list view, sorted by start time and include all the columns you need.